# for loop inside array filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let say I have two arrays

From here I want to filter arr1 with arr2 condition (assuming arr2 = arr1 id).
I have tried this code but only return first condition.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Jhon"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Barbara"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Rio"
  }
];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 5];


const filter = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const output = arr1.filter(value => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (value.id !== arr2[i]) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  })
  console.log(output);
};

filter(arr1, arr2);
// output = [{id: 1, name: "Jhon"}]
// intended output [{id: 1, name: "Jhon"}, {id: 2, name: "Barbara}]
```

Anyone can tell me what I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: Your `return true;` is *inside* the `for` loop body, so it runs on the first loop iteration if `value.id !== arr2[i]` is false. Move it *after* the `for` loop so you only `return false;` when none of the entries matched. Or you can use `some`: `.filter(value => arr2.some(v => v === value.id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the dupe why it did not work and then vastly simplify this

```js
const arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: "Jhon" }, { id: 2, name: "Barbara" }, { id: 3, name: "Rio" } ];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 5];

const filter = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter(({id}) => arr2.includes(id))

console.log(filter(arr1,arr2))
```

Comment: Heh, I had the arrays backward in my mind, hence reaching for `some` instead of `includes` in my comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was wondering. A bit like a woman we know who sees everything as a reduce